# Enable CORS on Web API 2 /Token endpoint

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api2

Running into a bit of a CORS issue here. You probably know the one...

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:59365/Token' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
>   HTTP ok status.

So turns out I need to enable CORS on the Web API project so I ran `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` and added `config.EnableCors()` to `WebApiConfig.cs`

This hasn't helped since the `/Token` endpoint in question is, for all intents and purposes, built into OAuth so I can't touch that code to add the `[EnableCors]` annotation that's apparently necessary to make this work:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions {
     TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
     ... 
}
```

So the last idea that I've got (that I'm not going to try now as it's 1am and I have to work tomorrow) is to divert the login to a controller that I can manipulate and use that as a sort of "middle man" between my app and /Token though admittedly I'm not sure what the code of this middle man might look like...

I assume there's a more efficient way of dealing with this problem of which I'm unaware and I'm hoping you who are likely smarter than me might be kind enough to share.

Bottom line is if I can't post to /Token, I can't authenticate my app to the service and both bits of software are useless. I don't understand why this is a thing or how I'm supposed to address this problem...

Comment: I am looking for the same.. did you found any solution ?

Comment: I'm afraid not; I don't even remember which project this was. Sorry I can't help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove all CORS based code from WebApiConfig file and add the below code in your Startup file in App_Start folder

```
   public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    }
```